# Core Plot Pan Gesture Recognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-plot, uipangesturerecognizer

Hi there CorePlot fans,

I got a little tricky question: **is it possible to call the auto panGestureRecognizer in my graph?**
 Because I would like to limit the options were it gets called with:

```
[panRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail recognizer2];
```

and also the other way around!

TXH for any useful answer!

Answer (score 0):

The instance variable that points to the built-in gesture recognizer is private, but you can find it in the `gestureRecognizers` array of the hosting view.

Comment: but in the hostingView array is no panGesture listed!

Comment: Core Plot only uses a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. Horizontal and vertical scrolling is handled directly with touch events (began, moved, ended, cancelled). You can use a plot space delegate to control scrolling and zooming, or set `allowsUserInteraction` to `NO` on the plot space to disable it completely.